# How can I pull specific nested elements with the same tag in Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am really new to Python, so I am still trying to figure out Beautiful Soup. I am trying to scrape a website and pull five elements that immediately follow the tag I have found in my code.

I have tried next.element, which only pulls the text of the tag that I used in my soup.find, and I have tried next.sibling, which returns as blank.

There are a number of 'first' and 'last' classes on the page, so I have to specify which line I want with the text. Here is what I am trying to scrape:

```
 <li>
        <ul>
            <li class="first">Maintenance</li>
                        <li>$number1</li>
                        <li>$number2</li>
                        <li>$number3</li>
                        <li>$number4</li>
                        <li>$number5</li>
                    <li class="last">$linetotal</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

This what I am trying:

```
for x,y in zip(make, model):
    url = ('https://URL with variables goes here')
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
    search = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    html = search.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    search_results = soup.find('li', class_ = 'first', text = re.compile('Maintenance'))
    try:
        d = search_results.next_element
        print(d)
    except:
        print('pass')
```

The ultimate goal will be to append the array of number1:number5 into a list, but with the code above, the output is just 'Maintenance'. Where am I going wrong? Also, since I am so new, if you are able to provide context as well, I would be very appreciative.

Comment: Do you want every occurrence of class first and has text maintenance then the li children? Or only the first occurrence? Can you share the url? Does maintenance only occur the once and in a fixed position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your example, simplest way would be to append to the results list all the `li` elements that don't have a class defined.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """ <li>
        <ul>
            <li class="first">Maintenance</li>
                        <li>$number1</li>
                        <li>$number2</li>
                        <li>$number3</li>
                        <li>$number4</li>
                        <li>$number5</li>
                    <li class="last">$linetotal</li>
        </ul>
    </li>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
start = soup.find('li', class_ = 'first').parent
result = []

for ele in start.find_all('li'):

    if not ele.get('class'):
        result.append(ele.text)

print(result)
```

Outputs:

```
['$number1', '$number2', '$number3', '$number4', '$number5']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an xpath expression with something like  tree.xpath

```
//li[@class='first' and text()='Maintenance']/following-sibling::li[not(@class)]
```

E.g.

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
# url = ''
# tree = html.fromstring( requests.get(url).content)
h = '''
 <li>
    <ul>
        <li class="first">Maintenance</li>
        <li>$number1</li>
        <li>$number2</li>
        <li>$number3</li>
        <li>$number4</li>
        <li>$number5</li>
        <li class="last">$linetotal</li>
    </ul>
</li>
'''
tree = fromstring(h)
items = [item.text for item in tree.xpath("//li[@class='first' and text()='Maintenance']/following-sibling::li[not(@class)]")]
print(items)
```

Comment: Did you try this? Your question specified you wanted to find after maintenance. This solution does that

Answer (score 0):

Something along the line of QHarr's answer, but somewhat different:

```
 h = '''
   <li>
     <ul>
       <li class="first">Maintenance</li>
       <li>$number1</li>
       <li>$number2</li>
       <li>$number3</li>
       <li>$number4</li>
       <li>$number5</li>
       <li class="last">$linetotal</li>
   </ul>
</li>

  '''
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.fromstring(h)
for cost in doc.xpath('//li'): 
   if not 'class' in cost.attrib:
      print(cost.text)
```

Output:

```
$number1
$number2
$number3
$number4
$number5
```